# Re-occuring subgroups of $S_n$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

The symmetric group has a number of families of subgroups also indexed by n such as $A_n$, $D_n$, or $AG(1,p)$. Are there other notable groups such as these which for any $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ exist for some $n > m$? I am particularly interested in such families of groups which satisfy the following condition:

1. The group contains no elements of order $n$
2. The group cannot be embedded in $S_m$ for $m<n$

Comment: I don't understand your question. Cayley's theorem says any finite group can be embedded in $S_n$ for sufficiently large $n$ (specifically, $n\geq |G|$).

Comment: The way I read it, it is about families of groups: a parametrization of groups by natural numbers (say $G_n, n \in \mathbb{N}$) with the additional properties that a) $G_n \subset S_n$ and b) $G_n$ does not contain an element of order $n$. Of course, written like this it easy to cheat: like defining $G_n = S_{n-1}$. Well perhaps it is not cheating. In certain situations the $S_{n-1}$-subgroups of $S_n$ are important...

Comment: Vincent is correct in his interpretation--I am sorry for the ambiguity. In this case I do not think I am interested in subgroups such as $S_{n-1}$. I should clarify another condition is that $G_n$ should not be embeddable in $S_{m}$ for $m < n$

Comment: What about $S_{n-2}\times S_2$?

Comment: By the way, if $n$ is a prime, then a subgroup of $S_n$ does not contain an element of order $n$ if and only if it is not transitive. Now, an intransitive subgroup embeds in $S_{n-i}\times S_i$ for some $i\in\{1,\ldots n-1\}$. Since you don't want to embed in $S_{n-1}$, then in fact $i\in\{2,\ldots n-2\}$.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm also not really interested in Young Subgroups, but I'll have to think about a way to add that in as a condition.